# Additional space under checkbox element

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Why is there additional space below checkbox? It is not identified in DevTools but expands its container on about 3-4 pixels.
I've tested it in Firefox and Edge browsers, it seems that checkbox has inconsistencies in its visualization (Firefox doesn't change the size of it despite the `height: 50px; width: 50px;`
I use Chrome 67 (on Windows 10). The problem seems the same in Edge.
Here is JSFiddle:
[extra space below checkbox](https://jsfiddle.net/ygdacntq/7/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: For creating a custom checkbox, use something like this https://codepen.io/Vestride/pen/dABHx

Comment: The space issue is related to what @Paulie_D mentioned

Comment: Ok, thank you very much